# convert for loop into dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6, dictionary-comprehension

I have a small program that works just fine.  I am trying to force myself to review\analyze my code in order to try to make my code (and myself) just a little better.

I was wondering if this small portion of code:

```
temp2 = {}
for key in sorted(temp1.keys()):
    temp2[key] = temp1[key]
```

couldn't be rewritten as a dictionary comprehension.

Due primarily to my profound lack of experience I am not able to 'convert'
this into a comprehension.

All the loop does is take dictionary `temp1`, sort it and place the newly sorted `key:value` pairs into `temp2`.

As I stated above, the whole thing works as is, but I am trying to learn
spotting patterns where I can make improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly translating this to a dictionary comprehension is easy:

```
temp2 = {key: value for key, value in sorted(temp1.items())}
```

In case you don't want to use the `value` as tie-breaker if the keys are equal you could also provide a `key` so you're only sorting based on the `key`:

```
temp2 = {key: value for key, value in sorted(temp1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])}
```

Even though dictionaries are "ordered" in python-3.6 doesn't mean you should rely on it (the orderedness is officially just a side-effect!). Better to use an `OrderedDict` and be on the safe side:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
temp2 = OrderedDict([(key, value) for key, value in sorted(temp1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])])
```

Comment: Since your second answer worked perfectly I was wondering what the third option (involving OrderedDict) brings to the table.  When would option #3 be a more appropriate choice?  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkS Ah, that's a bit complicated. Dictionaries themselves are **unordered**, so sorting a dictionary is by definition doomed to fail. But starting with 3.6 dictionaries are now **ordered**, but officially that's just an "implementation detail" that could change any moment. So if you want it to work with different Python versions or want to "play safe" you absolutely have to use the `OrderedDict`. I mostly added it because it's still the best practice to prefer `OrderedDict` over `dict` if you need it ordered. :)